# Is there any health/fitness band which can be integrated with ionic framework?

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I need to know whether is there any fitness band which can be integrated with ionic framework? I have did research over google and i found this one.

[https://github.com/betomaluje/Mi-Band[It's](https://github.com/betomaluje/Mi-Band%5BIt%27s) Mi-Band integration with ionic framework with ionic but i am looking any other suggestions.][1]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ionic Framework with Cordova, you should be able to access Xiomi Mi Band 1,2 and Amazafit Bip information with the plugin https://github.com/mmig/cordova-plugin-gadgetbridge